# How to release Memory when switching view controllers in non ARC project

Tags: ios, memory-management, uiviewcontroller, memory-leaks

I want to switch between two view controllers which containes lot of imageviews and other image content. When i switch back to another view controller memory is not released. When i go back same amount of memory will be loaded again. Following is how i switch to another viewcontroller.

```
 MainViewController *mView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"main_view_controller"];
            lView.modalTransitionStyle= UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
            [self presentViewController:mView animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Can anyone help me find a way which will release memory when switching back to another viewcontroller. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Rigth now it is automatically release memory. then why you are bothered about release memory. Now you can't user ' release ' method on objc

Answer (score 0):

The cause of this is that you have some retained ivars that's being referenced from/to another class for example.

By using release on an object, that objects reference count is decreased by one. So if your class have a higher reference count than 1 (in a perfect example. In a real implementation this will differ), it will not be released.

Be sure to set the view to nil also. One thing that might make your view to retain is if you for example have a timer or observer in your "MainViewController". Then, if using release on that class, the reference count will still be higher than 0 and thus your view will never be released.

Instruments is a good tool you can use to find scenarios like yours in your program. Find out more [How to use Instruments - RayWenderlich.com](http://www.raywenderlich.com/23037/how-to-use-instruments-in-xcode)